# SAPUI5 Localized Date Validation

Tags: javascript, validation, date, sapui5

Does anybody know which date formats SAPUI5 is using to validate localized dates with sap.m.DatePicker?

Example: 
When using sap.m.DatePicker with displayFormat "MMMM d, y" in en-US, I type "12/31/18" and it gets converted to "December 31, 2018", but when I type "12/31/2018" it doesn't seem to be a valid input.

Comment: its not valid  because the inputs are different

Comment: What format are you specifying for the input?

Comment: @RobG I only specified a displayFormat as mentioned above.

Comment: A date parser needs to know the format it's parsing, otherwise you're letting it guess. The [*documentation*](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/api/sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat/methods/parse) is not helpful, it seems to expect the parse format to be the same as the output format which does not seem correct given the information in your OP.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out!
If there is no valueFormat provided for the sap.m.DatePicker, the input validation is based on the displayFormat and a couple of fallback formats which are specific to the given locale. In en_US the fallback formats are:

MMddyyyy
MMddyy
M/d/yy
MMM d, y
yyyy-MM-dd
yyyyMMdd
MMddyyyy
MMddyy

"12/31/2018" doesn't match any of those formats and therefore is not considered valid.
I created this tool so you can check the locale specific formats and test some standard or custom display formats:
http://jsbin.com/xalinujafi/edit?output

Getting the DatePicker looks like this:

```
var oDateFormat = sap.ui.core.format.DateFormat.getDateInstance({style: 'long'});
var oDate = new sap.m.DatePicker({
    width: '19.25rem',
    displayFormat: oDateFormat.oFormatOptions.pattern,
    change: function(oEvent){
        var oSource = oEvent.getSource();
        var oFormat = oSource._oDisplayFormat;
        if (!oFormat.parse(oSource.getValue())) {
            oSource.setValueState("Error");
            oSource.setValueStateText("Invalid Input");
        } else {
            oSource.setValueState("None");
            oSource.setValueStateText("");
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I suggest that is a very ordinary way to handle parsing, and that you use a real parser instead, such as [*fecha.js*](https://github.com/taylorhakes/fecha).